# Using Scroll Wheel with Horizontal Scroll

Tags: html, jquery, css, scroll, mousewheel

I'm relatively new to web design. I'm using PHP, HTML, CSS and JQuery in my design.
I have created a scrolling image viewer with images as inline-blocks. The height is fixed to 100% of the screen so that the vertical scroll bar should never be used. I have allowed for scrolling in the x direction so the user can scroll horizontally through the images.

This all works however the scroll wheel does nothing. Is there anyway that I can make vertical scroll input from the mouse translate to horizontal scrolling?

CSS:

```
    .photoViewer {
    white-space: nowrap;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    padding-top: 50px;

}

.photoViewer li {

   display: inline-block;
   height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
}

.photoViewer li img{
    height: 100% ;
    width: auto;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Comment: @freedomn-m Isn't that why he is *new*? To answer your question, yes it is possible, with `javascript`/`jquery`

Comment: @freedomn-m The first article that you linked gives examples of website that do exactly what I'm asking and do it well.

Answer (score 1):

There is a jQuery plugin that can help you accomplish this called [jQuery Mousewheel](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mousewheel). Chris Coyier from CSS tricks used it in his example [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/horz-scroll-with-mouse-wheel/) which essentially translates Y axis scrolling into X axis scrolling:

```
// Code by Chris Coyier
$(function() {
    $("body").mousewheel(function(event, delta) {
        this.scrollLeft -= (delta * 30);
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [wheel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/wheel) event and translate deltaY to X.

Essentially:

```
$(".inner").on("wheel", function() { 
    var outer = $(this).closest(".outer");
    outer.scrollLeft(outer.scrollLeft() + e.originalEvent.deltaY);
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

but this is a bit jumpy, so you can add an animate - testing made this very clunky if too large an animation time, hence the exta `.stop()`.

You could probably achieve a better animation / smoother scroll using css transitions.

```js
$("#inner").on("wheel", function(e) {
  var outer = $(this).closest("#outer")
  //outer.scrollLeft(outer.scrollLeft() + e.originalEvent.deltaY)
  outer.stop(false,false).animate({scrollLeft:"+="+e.originalEvent.deltaY}, 50)
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
#outer {
  display:block;
  width:200px;
  height:100px;
  overflow-y:hidden;
  overflow-x:scroll;
  border:1px solid red
}
#inner {
  display:block;
  width: 500px;
  height:100px;
  border:1px solid blue;
  background: blue;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,red,orange,yellow,green,blue,indigo,violet);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(left,red,orange,yellow,green,blue,indigo,violet);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left,red,orange,yellow,green,blue,indigo,violet);
  background: linear-gradient(to right, red,orange,yellow,green,blue,indigo,violet); 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='outer'>
<div id='inner'>
</div>
</div>
```

(apparently don't use [mousehweel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mousewheel) as it's non-standard - it could be that jquery handles this for you).